AndroidStudio Cannot access member because 'R' has primitive type int
On an AndroidStudio project that previously worked now getting this error.
"Cannot access member because 'R' has primitive type int".
Tried the "Replace with qualifier" option but that didn't work.
Studio version is Koala, gradle is 8.5


Can you add your import statements?
